# Negative Pell's Equation: Prove that $k=3$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I made this problem (while solving another problem) but I haven't been able to prove it.

Let $x,y,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove that if $x^2-(k^2-4)y^2=-1$ then $k=3$.

Any pointers are appreciated, but a solution would be great.

An interesting observation is that $k^2-4=p$ for a prime $p$ has the unique solution $k=3$ (and $p=5$), so perhaps we can show that $k^2-4$ must be a prime? Then the result will follow.

Thanks!

Comment: If you change the -1 to +1 then $k=17, y = 144, x=2431$ works.... Not the same problem though.

Comment: There may be a solution to $x^2-221y^2=-1$ ($k=15$, $221=13\times17$).

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's not solvable for $k=15$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [simple continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Reduced_surds) for this is entirely predictable and provable. First note that $k$ cannot be even, as $-1$ is not a square mod 4. Also $k \neq 1 \pmod 4$ because then both $k+2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $k-2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ Both factors are divisible by a prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ hence $-1$ is not a quadratic residue.

We are left with $k \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ Take
$$ k = 4n+3 $$
with $$ n \geq 1.  $$
Also take
$$  a_0 = \lfloor \sqrt {k^2 - 4} \rfloor = k-1. $$
The continued fraction is
$$  \langle a_0; 1,2n,2,2n,1,2a_0 \rangle.  $$
I should point out that $a_0 + \sqrt {k^2 - 4}$ is a "reduced surd" in the sense meant by the wikipedia selection I link above. The continued fraction for it is 
$$  \langle 2a_0, 1,2n,2,2n,1, 2a_0, 1,2n,2,2n,1, 2a_0, 1,2n,2,2n,1, \ldots \rangle  $$ forever.

The primitively represented values of $x^2 - (k^2 - 4) y^2$ given by the convergents of the continued fraction are
$$ 1, \; 4, \; -(4n+1), \; -(8n+1)  $$
so we do not get $-1$ as soon as $n \geq 1.$

The fixed length of the continued fraction reflects this polynomial identity below: first note, with $k = 4n+3,$ we have $k^2 - 4 = 16n^2 + 24 n + 5.$ The identity is
$$\color{blue}{ \left( 32 n^3 + 72 n^2 + 48 n + 9 \right)^2 - \left( 16 n^2 + 24 n + 5 \right) \left(8n^2 + 12n + 4 \right)^2 = 1}.  $$

$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 4n+2 & & 1 & & 2n & & 2 & & 2n & & 1 & & 8n+4 \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{4n+2}{1} &  &  \frac{4n+3}{1} & &  \frac{8n^2+10n+2}{2n+1}  & & \frac{16n^2 +24n+7}{4n+3} & &  \frac{32n^3 +56n^2+24n+2}{8n^2+8n+1} & &   \frac{32n^3+72n^2+48n+9}{8n^2+12n+4}  & &    \\
              \\
 & 1 & & -8n-1  &  &  4 & &  -4n-1  & & 4 & &  -8n-1 & &   1  & &       
\end{array}
$$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 45


0  form   1 12 -9   delta  -1
1  form   -9 6 4   delta  2
2  form   4 10 -5   delta  -2
3  form   -5 10 4   delta  2
4  form   4 6 -9   delta  -1
5  form   -9 12 1   delta  12
6  form   1 12 -9

 disc   180
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
17  216
24  305


 Pell automorph 
161  1080
24  161

Pell unit 
161^2 - 45 * 24^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
7^2 - 45 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

45      3^2 *  5
=======================================================

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 117


0  form   1 20 -17   delta  -1
1  form   -17 14 4   delta  4
2  form   4 18 -9   delta  -2
3  form   -9 18 4   delta  4
4  form   4 14 -17   delta  -1
5  form   -17 20 1   delta  20
6  form   1 20 -17

 disc   468
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
49  1020
60  1249


 Pell automorph 
649  7020
60  649

Pell unit 
649^2 - 117 * 60^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
11^2 - 117 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

117      3^2 *  13
========================================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 221


0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25

 disc   884
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
97  2800
112  3233


 Pell automorph 
1665  24752
112  1665

Pell unit 
1665^2 - 221 * 112^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
15^2 - 221 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

221      13 *  17

================================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 357


0  form   1 36 -33   delta  -1
1  form   -33 30 4   delta  8
2  form   4 34 -17   delta  -2
3  form   -17 34 4   delta  8
4  form   4 30 -33   delta  -1
5  form   -33 36 1   delta  36
6  form   1 36 -33

 disc   1428
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
161  5940
180  6641


 Pell automorph 
3401  64260
180  3401

Pell unit 
3401^2 - 357 * 180^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
19^2 - 357 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

357      3 * 7 *  17
=============================================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 525


0  form   1 44 -41   delta  -1
1  form   -41 38 4   delta  10
2  form   4 42 -21   delta  -2
3  form   -21 42 4   delta  10
4  form   4 38 -41   delta  -1
5  form   -41 44 1   delta  44
6  form   1 44 -41

 disc   2100
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
241  10824
264  11857


 Pell automorph 
6049  138600
264  6049

Pell unit 
6049^2 - 525 * 264^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
23^2 - 525 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

525      3 * 5^2 *  7
=================================================================
```

Comment: If the lenght of the fraction is even then it's not solvable